# Run headless firefox in Selenium grid remote

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-grid

How to run Firefox and Internet Explorer on Selenium remote server in headless mode using python?

Comment: I need to run headless firefox using "Remote Server" not using webdriver.

Comment: Need to run firefox and IE in headless mode using "webdriver.Remote".